# Clear all apps user data with ADB without factory reset

Tags: applications, adb, internal-storage, delete

I'm trying to achieve the goal of clearing all app data using Git Bash on Windows, but I don't know exactly if this approach is wrong, because it shows FAILED on every line.

```
adb shell 'pm list packages' | sed -e "s/package\://" | xargs -n1 adb shell pm clear
```

1. **List all packages**

   ```
   adb shell 'pm list packages'
   ```
2. **Remove "package:" from the begining of each line**

   ```
   adb shell 'pm list packages' | sed -e "s/package\://"
   ```
3. **Execute "pm clear" on every package name**

   ```
   adb shell 'pm list packages' | sed -e "s/package\://" | xargs -n1 adb shell pm clear
   ```

Regards.

Comment: I wonder what's wrong with this. Seems to work fine when I tried a dry run. See if everything is fine and no special character is causing an issue. Replace pm clear with `pm path` and see if it also fails.

Comment: @Firelord: pm path is working correctly!!